# SIGABRT Error when using IBAction buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, iboutlet

**why did this happen?**

[image: why did this happen?]

Why do i get a Sigabrt when my action is perfectly linked? anything missing guys? Sorry -new to this.

**Perfectly connected right?**

[image: Perfectly connected right?]

Thanks guys and gals!

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController Button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa27bc1e340'
//what the console states-

Comment: If you get a `SIGABRT` a message will be printed in the console telling you what went wrong.

Comment: Did you include a photo of code you took? Not even a screenshot but a photo?

Comment: Ok why did i get a minus. Do you guys not want beginners asking questions on this? Unfriendly indeed. AND it was a screenshot that was used in post on another help forum. Thanks guys . :(

Comment: This can happen if you delete a button and then add another one without deleting the old connection.

Comment: How do i go about and delete the old connection?

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F, search for the outlet/action name that triggered “unrecognized selector” error (in your case “Button” ... since it's such a generic term, I'd suggest refining the search criteria for “Find” » “Text” » “_Matching Word_” and make sure you select “Matching Case” rather than “Ignoring Case” in the case sensitivity search). That will find all references to “Button”, including any lingering invalid outlets. When you tap on the offending one (tap once to see the storyboard, tap again to see the outlet), you’ll be taken to the storyboard and may even see a warning. Hit ⊗ to remove.

Answer (score 0):

From storyboard, Select your viewController and check in the connection inspector tab.There you can find out all connections made from yor view controller.There may be some ofthem shown as " ! " mark.Delete those.

[image]